# Neo4j with C# in production

Tags: c#, api, rest, neo4j

Is anybody using Neo4j with the REST API in production? I've been looking at different implementations of the REST API out there and noticed this one has been downloaded quite a few times

http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/overview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ryan,

I'm one of the devs on the library. Our day-to-day project has a dedicated team of 5 developers, and uses Neo4j in production (on Azure, just for good measure). As we build out our solution, we have kept building the library along the way.

Our solution depends 100% on this library being reliable.

HTH,

Tatham

Comment: Thanks, do you plan on releasing this library?

Comment: We have. You linked to it in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of production instances out there, basically anybody using one of the REST bindings, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tutorials-rest.html, is running against it. Maybe ask on the mailing list, http://groups.google.com/group/neo4j/about

Answer (score 0):

You can see a sample application that uses this library and is open source here:

hg clone https://bitbucket.org/romiko/frictionfree

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this question with a more current option consider using the Neo4jClient from NuGet.  The package and links to the project site are at http://nuget.org/packages/Neo4jClient